# No gutter between 2 bootstrap 3.x panel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, panel, gutter

I need to have 2 panel in Bootstrap 3.x horizontally. I added the normal codes like this:

```
<div class="panel panel-default col-md-6">
    <div class="panel-heading">Heading</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        Something ...
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default col-md-6">
    <div class="panel-heading">Heading</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        Something ...
    </div>
</div>
```

But there is no gutter between these 2 panel and they appear like this:

[image: Captured image]
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about making the panels children on the bootstrap columns?
https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/MVomeX

```
<div class="col-md-6">
 <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Heading</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        Something ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Heading</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        Something ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```